# Volley : adding array of request to queue

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm putting the volley requests to an array and then i' using `for` statement for adding request to volley queue like this (pseudo code) :

```
ArrayList<Requst> array = new ArrayList<Requst>()
volleyRequest req = //some code
volleyRequest req2 = //some code
array.add(req)
array.add(req2)
```

And on another class i'm using :

```
for(Requst r : array )
{
   volley.newRequestQueue.add(req, tag);
}
```

But this loop did not continue until first request does not finished!
What should i do?
Is there any way for adding array of requests to volley without loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the singleton pattern to add multiple request in volley library as specified in the [link](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html)

Comment: I used singleton pattern but still i have this problem.When i adding multpe request to queue with LOOP,first request finishing and then next request adding,i understanding it from volley logs

Answer (score 0):

Check that out, you need to create a RequestQueue:
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html